# Check if after a specific charachter there is white space php

Tags: php

I am trying to check if after a specific char there is white space. The specific char that I want to see this is `/` (or slash). I tried.

```
$url = 'stackoverflow.com/';
if (preg_match('//\S/', $url)) {
echo "Please remove ending slash from URL";
} else {
echo "We don't accept subfolders/subpages";
}
```

I get error: `Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '\'`.
Please help me I am a noob on regex.

Comment: You should escape the second slash, because the regex parser thinks it's the end of the pattern. Or, use different pattern delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern is being opened with a `/` so PHP is viewing your `/` as the end of a pattern and then looking to see the rest of the string as modifiers to it (treating multiple lines as one, ignore case, perform global search.

In order to find the slash, you will need to escape it:

```
preg_match('/\/\S/', $url)
```

Alternatively you can use a different character to delimit your pattern like:

```
preg_match('~/\S~', $url)
```